# Writing a method that pulls information from two different arrays and prints it into a JTextField

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, jtextarea

The goal of this project is to create four classes: a Student class, a GradStudent class, a Manager class, and a GUI class. Within the GUI there are two radio buttons: one for Student and one for GradStudent. Depending on which one is selected, the Manager class is supposed to be responsible for creating and storing the Student or GradStudent objects by use of two arrays. I have also added a button to my GUI which is supposed to print the all of the students who have entered "Computer Science" as their major. However, I am running into trouble in regards to how to writ this method. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. I will post my classes below. Thank you!

**Student Class**

```
public class Student {
    protected String name;
    protected String address;
    protected double balance;
    protected String major;

    // Constructs fields
    public Student(String name, String address, String balance, String major) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.major = major;
        try {
            this.balance = Double.parseDouble(balance);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            this.balance = 0;
        }
    }

    public String setName(String name) {
        return name;
    }

    public String setAddress(String address) {
        return address;
    }

    public double setBalance(double balance) {
        return balance;
    }

    public String setMajor(String major) {
        return major;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return ("Name: " + this.name + " Address: " + this.address
                + " Balance: " + this.balance + " Major: " + this.major);
    }
}
```

**GradStudent Class**

```
public class GradStudent extends Student {

    public GradStudent(String name, String address, String balance, String major) {
        super(name, address, balance, major);
    }



    public String toString() {
        return ("Name: " + this.name + " Address: " + this.address
                + " Balance: " + this.balance + " Major: " + this.major);
    }
}
```

**Manager Class**

```
public class Manager {
    public Student[] students = new Student[50];
    public int counter1 = 0;

    public GradStudent[] gradStudents = new GradStudent[50];
    public int counter2 = 0;

    public Manager() {

    }

    public void addStudent(String name, String address, String balance, String major) {
        Student student1 = new Student(name, address, balance, major);
        students[counter1] = student1;
                counter1++;
    }
    public String getLastStudent() {
        return "Student added: " + students[counter1-1] +"\n";
    }

    public void addGradStudent(String name, String address, String balance, String major) {
        GradStudent student2 = new GradStudent(name, address, balance, major);
        gradStudents[counter2] = student2;
                counter2++;
    }
    public String getLastGradStudent() {
        return "Graduate Student added: " + gradStudents[counter2-1] +"\n";
    }

    public String getAverageBalance(){
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < counter1; i++) {
            sum += students[i].setBalance(counter1);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < counter2; i++) {
            sum+= students[i].setBalance(counter2);
        }

        double average = sum / (counter1+counter2);
        return average+"";
        }

}
```

**GUI Class**

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    private JRadioButton jrbStudent = new JRadioButton("Student");
    private JRadioButton jrbGraduate = new JRadioButton("Graduate");
    private JTextField name = new JTextField(20);
    private JTextField address = new JTextField(20);
    private JTextField balance = new JTextField(20);
    private JTextField major = new JTextField(20);
    private JButton jbtSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    private JTextArea echoStudent = new JTextArea();

    private JButton printStudentNames = new JButton("Print Student's Names");
    private JButton printGradStudentNames = new JButton(
            "Print Graduate Student's Names");
    private JButton calcBalance = new JButton(
            "Calculate Average Balance of All Students");
    private JButton compSciMajor = new JButton(
            "Displays Computer Science Major Students");

    private Manager m1 = new Manager();

    public GUI() {

        // Creates panel P1 and adds the components
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9, 1, 10, 10));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Name: "));
        p1.add(name);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Address: "));
        p1.add(address);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Balance: "));
        p1.add(balance);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Major: "));
        p1.add(major);
        p1.add(jrbStudent);
        p1.add(jrbGraduate);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Submit Button: "));
        p1.add(jbtSubmit);
        p1.add(printStudentNames);
        p1.add(printGradStudentNames);
        p1.add(calcBalance);
        p1.add(compSciMajor);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Submitted Text: "));

        // Creates a radio-button group to group both buttons
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(jrbStudent);
        group.add(jrbGraduate);

        // Adds the panel and text area to the frame
        add(p1);
        p1.add(echoStudent);
        echoStudent.setEditable(false);

        // Creates a listener and registers it with the submit button
        SubmitListener l1 = new SubmitListener();
        jbtSubmit.addActionListener(l1);

        // Creates a listener and registers it with the radio buttons
        JRBListener l2 = new JRBListener();
        jrbStudent.addActionListener(l2);
        jrbGraduate.addActionListener(l2);

        // Creates a listener and registers it with the PrintStudentNames button
        StudentListener l3 = new StudentListener();
        printStudentNames.addActionListener(l3);

        // Creates a listener and registers it with the PrintGradStudentNames button
        GradStudentListener l4 = new GradStudentListener();
        printGradStudentNames.addActionListener(l4);

        // Creates a listener and registers it with the calcBalance button
        CalcBalanceListener l5 = new CalcBalanceListener();
        calcBalance.addActionListener(l5);
    }

    // Class to handle the submit button
    class SubmitListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            Student[] students = new Student[50];
            int arrayLocation = 0;

            Student student1 = new Student(name.getText(), address.getText(),
                    balance.getText(), major.getText());
            // Checks remaining array space
            if (arrayLocation < 50) {
                students[arrayLocation] = student1;
                ++arrayLocation;
            }
            // Echos back entered text while storing the previous text
            echoStudent.setText(echoStudent.getText() + "\n"
                    + student1.toString());
        }
    }

    // Class to handle the radio buttons
    class JRBListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b) {
            if (b.getSource() == jrbStudent) {
                m1.addStudent(name.getText(), address.getText(),
                        balance.getText(), major.getText());
                echoStudent
                        .setText("Created Student: \n" + m1.getLastStudent());
            }

            if (jrbGraduate.isSelected()) {
                m1.addGradStudent(name.getText(), address.getText(),
                        balance.getText(), major.getText());
                echoStudent.setText("Created Graduate Student: \n"
                        + m1.getLastGradStudent());
            }
        }
    }
    // Class to handle the "Print Student's Names" button
    class StudentListener extends Manager implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent c) {

            echoStudent.setText(m1.students[counter1].name);

        }

    }
    // Class to handle the "Print Graduate Student's Names" button
    class GradStudentListener extends Manager implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent d) {

            echoStudent.setText(m1.gradStudents[counter2].name);

        }

    }
    // Class to handle the "Calculate Average Balance of All Students" button
    class CalcBalanceListener extends Manager implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            echoStudent.setText(getAverageBalance());
        }
    }
    // Class to handle the "Displays Computer Science Major Students" button
    class CompSciMajorListener extends Manager implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI frame = new GUI();
        frame.setTitle("Information Interface");
        frame.setSize(1200, 900);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you should do the following: 
in a method you will have to loop through the array of students (which you called students), get each student, check what major is assigned to it (compare it with "computer science") and print the ones that do CS.

It would be something in lines:

```
private static void checkMajor(Student [] studentList) {
    for(Student s : studentList){
        if(s.major.equals("Computer Science"){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can change the return type of the method from void to student and change the println statement to return s if you want to display it in GUI or do something with it (my code prints it to the command line).